# When is it useful for an associated constant to use a lifetime other than 'static?

Tags: rust, constants, associated-types

[RFC 1623](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1623-static.md), stabilized in Rust 1.17.0, made it so that we do not have to explicitly specify the `'static` lifetime in a `static` or `const`:

```
const MY_DEFAULT_NAME: &str = "Anna";
//                      ^ Look, ma! No 'static!
```

[RFC 195](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0195-associated-items.md) defined *associated constants*, which were stabilized in Rust 1.20.0:

```
struct A;

impl A {
    const B: i32 = 42;
}
```

When trying to combine these two, an error is raised:

```
struct A;

impl A {
    const MY_DEFAULT_NAME: &str = "Anna";
}
```

```
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
 --> src/main.rs:4:28
  |
4 |     const MY_DEFAULT_NAME: &str = "Anna";
  |                            ^ expected lifetime parameter
```

The [related GitHub issue #38831](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/38831) has [a comment](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/38831#issuecomment-305864245):

> We decided against it because, in that case, there might be other
>   lifetimes you would want. For example:
>
> ```
> trait Foo<'a> {
>     const T: &'a str;
> }
> ```
>
> that said, revisiting this explanation, it feel a bit weak, since the
>   value of an associated constant would still have to be all consisting
>   of static data. So it seems like `'static` is a pretty good default if
>   you don't say otherwise.

What is an example of an associated constant with a non-`'static` lifetime? What benefit does providing a non-`'static` lifetime bring?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One might consider a constant that is a function:

```
trait Foo<'a> {
    const BAR: fn(&Self) -> &'a str;
}

struct MyFoo<'a> {
    x: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> Foo<'a> for MyFoo<'a> {
    const BAR: fn(&Self) -> &'a str = my_bar;
}

fn my_bar<'a>(a: &MyFoo<'a>) -> &'a str {
    &a.x
}
```

Right now, I can't think of how this would be more beneficial than a method.